# SQL use count or sum for specific result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to get result with native SQL query as it is presented on below picture, currently im not sure if there is any way to get this result with using only SQL.

I was around this query, but no idea currently further:

```
 SELECT 
    receipts.client_code clientCode, 
    date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date) monthYear,
    COUNT(date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date)) receipts,
    subReceipts.total total
    FROM receipts
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
      receipts.client_code clientCode, 
      date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date) monthYear,
      COUNT(date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date)) total
      FROM receipts

      GROUP BY 
      receipts.client_code,
      date_trunc('MON' ,receipts.create_date)
      ORDER BY 
      date_trunc('MON' ,receipts.create_date)  
     ) subReceipts ON subReceipts.clientCode = receipts.client_code
   GROUP BY 
    receipts.client_code,
    date_trunc('MON' ,receipts.create_date),
    subReceipts.total 
   ORDER BY 
    date_trunc('MON' ,receipts.create_date)
```

Sample sql data and db table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE receipts 
(
receipt_id int primary key,
client_code varchar not null,
create_date date not null
);

insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (1, 'fx90', to_date('2016/01/11', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (2, 'fx90', to_date('2016/02/12', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (3, 'fx90', to_date('2016/02/20', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (4, 'fx90', to_date('2016/03/11', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (5, 'fx90', to_date('2016/03/12', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
insert into receipts (receipt_id, client_code, create_date) values (6, 'fx90', to_date('2016/03/19', 'yyyy/MM/dd'));
```

Example result

[image: sample result with params]

Comment: Looks like you want to add a "running total" to each row.  `DATE_TRUNC` is not a valid MySQL function, so it's not clear why this question is tagged with mysql.

Comment: true - mysql tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postgresql:

```
SELECT clientCode, monthYear, receipts,
       sum(receipts) over(order by monthYear) as total
  FROM (
     SELECT receipts.client_code clientCode, 
            date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date) monthYear,
            COUNT(1) receipts
       FROM receipts
      GROUP BY receipts.client_code, monthYear
  ) X
 ORDER BY monthYear
```

Comment: It is this what I looked for - can You tell me for what is used 'count(1)' 
It appear just for use group by ?

Comment: @PDave `count()` counting any NOT NULL values. `1` is not null :) `count(1)` is equal to `count(date_trunc('MON', receipts.create_date))`, but may be faster

Answer (score 2):

Assuming mysql, you could just do:

```
set @running_total := 0;
SELECT
    client_code, 
    CONCAT(MONTH(create_date), ' - ', YEAR(create_date)) as month_year,
    COUNT(receipt_id) AS receipts_month,
    (@running_total := @running_total + COUNT(receipt_id)) as total_receipts
FROM receipts
GROUP BY client_code, MONTH(create_date), YEAR(create_date)
ORDER BY receipt_id;
```